# ListView child to new Intent

Tags: android

I have followed a tutorial and have an expandable ListView and wanted to link the child to the a new activity - how would I go about doing this? I'm new to Android so any help would be much appreciated :)

```
createGroupList();

    createCollection();

    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.search_list);
    final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupList, advSearchOption);
    expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                    groupPosition, childPosition);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
private void createGroupList() {
    groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupList.add("Advanced Search");
}
private void createCollection() {
    // preparing laptops collection(child)
    String[] searches = { "Height", "Weight",
            "Hair Colour" };
    advSearchOption = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    for (String advSearch : groupList) {
        if (advSearch.equals("Advanced Search")) {
            loadChild(searches);
        }

        advSearchOption.put(advSearch, childList);
    }
}
private void loadChild(String[] searchOptions) {
    childList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String model : searchOptions)
        childList.add(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Intents here is the documentation for Intents on Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

But basically, where you have the toast you have to do something like this:

```
Intent childIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivity(childIntent);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, how would I specify which item in my childlist would link to the new activity?

Comment: @rory you have some data bind to your child item, you can get the data via getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) and put some data into the intent

Comment: Hi @jobcrazy, I want height to link to a new activity
String[] searches = { "Height", "Weight",
            "Hair Colour" };

Answer (score 0):

To send data to the new Activity.You can write something like this

```
Intent childIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
childIntent.putExtra("bind_value", (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                    groupPosition, childPosition));
startActivity(childIntent);
```

and retrive the value in new Activity's onCreate().

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that gives me an error Cannot resolve constructor :(

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, java.lang.class

Comment: change "Intent childIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class)"'s this to your activity context. You should read more about the intent docs.

Comment: ChildActivity must have a public constructor